# Unable to select video element using document.querySelectorAll('video');

Tags: javascript, html5-video, twitch

I spend time in a lot of twitch channels for networking and viewing multiple streams at once.  I'd like to have the ability to quickly change the volume without having to click every single one.

I've begun by attempting to access the video tag via javascript with the following, but I keep getting "undefined" in console.

`var vid = document.querySelectorAll('video');`

Eventually I planned to use the volume function/property of the object to adjust the volume, or the mute function, but I'm stuck on trying to select the object.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a HTMLCollection. You need to use `querySelector` instead if you only need the first element result.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML too?

Comment: @AndrewBone I'm not sure that's a good idea.  Just try any twitch channel and you'll have your HTML easier than I can paste it here without it being altered or without the js timers and listeners running on it (which may be the culprit?).

Comment: I found that if I remove "var" it works.  I don't recall this being a problem a couple of years ago.  Is this something they added in that time, and do any of you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: It is most likely that the video is in an iframe tag